# How to host laravel and reactjs apps together

Tags: mysql, reactjs, wordpress, laravel

Does anyone know where i can host laravel(php) + mysql app and js(react) app together ? I have some troubles with fetching data from my backend end points. I got my ReactApp on github pages and heroku. My backend server is on another host. When I try to fetch something using fetch API:

```
fetch("https://pw-inz.cba.pl/inz_be/public/api/articles", {method: 'GET'}).then(response => { return response.json(); }).then(data => { return data; }).catch(err => { throw new Error(err); });
```

I got an error:

```
The page at 'https://rmdv2.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://pw-inz.cba.pl/inz_be/public/api/articles'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I thought.. Ok.. seems kinda easy to fix, changed http to https and then:

```
net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

What is wrong? How should I host my backend to get it work with my front app?

Comment: Cert common name is the website name.  The hostname does not match the requested name.  Check the common name in the certificate an try to match it if possible.